Nested integration of the list of functions returns error
I have a list of expressions which I would like to integrate by nested integration. For any element from the list it works without issues (see end of the post), however, when I apply nested integration to the whole list I get an error. Can someone help me to understand what is matter and how to fix it ? I would like to continue to work with the list of functions as with the solid object.
Code:
ListExpressions = {x + y + z, 2 x + y + z, 3 x + y + z, 4 x + y + z, 5 x + y + z};
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[ListExpressions];
f2[K1_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, K1}];
f3[K1_?NumericQ, K2_?NumericQ, K3_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[K1, y, z], {y, 0, K2}, {z, 0, K3}];

f2[1, 1, 10]
f3[1, 1, 10]

Output:
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[x,1,10] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}.
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[x,1,10] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}.
Out[23]= NIntegrate[f[x, 1, 10], {x, 0, 1}]
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[x,1,10] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}.
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[x,1,10] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}.
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[x,1,10] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}.
During evaluation of In[19]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inum will be suppressed during this calculation.
During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand f2[1,y,z] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0,10}}.
Out[24]= NIntegrate[f2[1, y, z], {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 10}]

Everything is working fine when calculating a single element from a list of functions. One can use one of the lines, both return correct result for a given element after substitution to the code above:
IndexInList=3; (*can be 1, 2, 4, 5 as well*)
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[ListExpressions[[IndexInList]]];
(*OR*)
f2[K1_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, z][[IndexInList]], {x, 0, K1}];

*UPD 13.05.24 I tried to follow @LouisB's suggestion and I can conclude that the output for his approach gives vague values for f3. The results do not coincide with the one obtained for a single function from the list. Therefore, I would aware those who might resort to it, since the sequence of pure function application is not clear. Below, is the code for single functions:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ListExpressions = 1 x + y + z; (*OR N x + y + z*)
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[ListExpressions]
f2[K1_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, K1}];
f3[K1_?NumericQ, K2_?NumericQ, K3_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[K1, y, z], {y, 0, K2}, {z, 0, K3}];

f2[1, 1, 10]
f3[1, 1, 10]

(*11.5
60.*)


These are newbie errors, such as using upper-case letters to name functions or lists.  Also Evaluate[x + y + z] makes no sense.

I see, thank you. Do you have a solution to my issue ? I will be glad.

They are not always numeric. This works f[x_, y_, z_] := {x + y + z, 2  x + y + z, 3  x + y + z, 4  x + y + z,    5  x + y + z};  f2[K1_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=   NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, K1}]; f2[1, 1, 10]

@yarchik Thank you. Your suggestion works only for f2 for f3 it returns NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand x+y+z has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. Even when rid off ?NumericQ in f2 declaration, i.e. f2[K1_, y_, z_] . I cannot accept the proposal. "They are not always numeric" I do not agree, there is no symbolic calculations, and hence inputs have to be numeric only.

The intermediate solution I use is based on indexing, I did not find another option:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ListExpressions = {x + y + z, 2 x + y + z, 3 x + y + z, 4 x + y + z, 5 x + y + z};
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, KK_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[Indexed[ListExpressions, KK]]
f2[K1_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, KK_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, z, KK], {x, 0, K1}];
f3[K1_?NumericQ, K2_?NumericQ, K3_?NumericQ, KK_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[K1, y, z, KK], {y, 0, K2}, {z, 0, K3}];
f3[1,1,10,#]&/@Range[5]

(*{60.,65.,70.,75.,80.}*)
```

